# Mongo / Callbacks and Node troubles - callback is never called

Tags: node.js, callback, mongoose

The console statement never prints. I am not sure why. I am writing a function to list all characters (one user has many characters). The function isn't fully written yet. It simply returns the user with the specified email.

For some reason though it never returns. It outputs "This statement prints" But never the "why doesn't this ever print" statement!

```
UserSchema.methods.usersCharacters = function(email,cb){
  User.findOne( {'local.email' : email }).exec(function(err, user){
    if (err) console.log("oops");
    console.log("This statement prints");
    return user;
  });
};

UserSchema.methods.usersCharacters('a@gmail.com', function(err, okay){
  console.log("Why doesn't this ever print?");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to call the callback! DANGIT!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the callback ,see this :

```
var a = function(input ,callback){
   if ( input == "true" ){
      callback(null ,"it's true");
   } else {
      callback(true ,"it's false")
   }
};

a(true ,function(err ,res){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});

a(false ,function(err ,res){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(res);
});
```

I hope this help you to understand how to write callbacks.